# Animated loading gif image as a repeated background

Tags: css, animated-gif

I would like to find something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [opengraphicdesign.com](http://opengraphicdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/bar180.gif))</sub>

But that it can be a repeated background on an html element and looks like a whole block.

For example, a 80x80 gif as a repeated background in a 400x400 DIV that would give the illusion of a big 400x400 animated image.

Where can I find such a GIF

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I did it, after some fine cutting I've created the perfected image for the job.
Here is the gif image:
[image]

And here is a live demo http://jsfiddle.net/dtxSW/94/

**HTML:**

```
<span></span>
<span></span>
<div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQTRW.gif') repeat;
  height: 500px;
}

span {
  width: 108px;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQTRW.gif') repeat-x left;
}
```

This gif can be repeated infinitely and still look as one big whole animated image.

Answer (score 0):

Give [wegif.com](http://www.wegif.com/accounts/login/?next=/create/) a try

Answer (score -1):

a loading gif always has an animation - if you repeat the gif, this animation will play per image - i don't know if that looks very nice

Comment: I know, I was hoping someone knew of  a symetric gif that wouldn't look shoped up when repeated.

Comment: i don't think it will work. you'll have to create your own gif which is as large as you need it

Comment: It will work, I'm on my phone right now, but if you could test the image in my post you will see that it only misses(out of sync) by a bit, if i could find a way to crop that image I might make it work